# xarray.Dataset.to_zarr: overwrite data if exists with append_dim

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, zarr

With [xarray.Dataset.to_zarr](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_zarr.html?highlight=to_zarr#xarray-dataset-to-zarr) it is possible to write an xarray to a `.zarr` file and append new data along a dimension using the `append_dim` parameter.

However, if the coordinate of the new data for this dimension is already there, the existing data won't be replaced. Rather the same coordinate appears twice in the resulting dateset.

**Example using the data from [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#positional-indexing):**

Here I write 2 Datasets to the same .zarr file. The datasets are appended along the `space` dimension. Both datasets contain the same space coordinate `"IL"`

```
ds_A = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(4, 2),
    [
        ("time", pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)),
        ("space", ["IA", "IL"]),
    ],
).to_dataset(name="measurements")


ds_B = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(4, 2),
    [
        ("time", pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)),
        ("space", ["IL", "NY"]),
    ],
).to_dataset(name="measurements")


ds_A.to_zarr("weather.zarr", append_dim="space")
ds_B.to_zarr("weather.zarr", append_dim="space");
```

When reading the file, the second dataset didn't overwrite the data for the `"IL"` coordinate, but crated a new one:

```
xr.open_zarr("weather.zarr")


<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (space: 4, time: 4)
Coordinates:
  * space         (space) <U2 'IA' 'IL' 'IL' 'NY'
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-04
Data variables:
    measurements  (time, space) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(4, 2), meta=np.ndarray>
```

**This would be the desired result:**

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (space: 3, time: 4)
Coordinates:
  * space         (space) <U2 'IA'  'IL' 'NY'
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-04
Data variables:
    measurements  (time, space) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(3, 2), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to replace the data if the coordinate already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box way to do this, appending always adds the full dataset to the end.

However, version `0.16.2` of `xarray` introduced the keyword `region` to `to_zarr`, which lets you write to limited region of a `zarr` file.

You can use it, to overwrite the existing data:

```py
# write first dataset
ds_A.to_zarr("weather.zarr")

# read structure of dataset to see what's on disk
ds_ondisk = xr.open_zarr('weather.zarr/')

# get index of first new datapoint
start_ix, = np.nonzero(~np.isin(ds_B.space, ds_ondisk.space))

# region of new data
region_new = slice(start_ix[0], ds_B.space.size)

# append structure of new data (compute=False means no data is written)
ds_B.isel(space=region_new).to_zarr("weather.zarr", append_dim='space', compute=False)

# get updated dataset size and create slice
ds_ondisk = xr.open_zarr('weather.zarr/')
region_update = slice(start_ix[0], ds_ondisk.space.size)

# write new data to zarr (time needs to be dropped)
ds_B.drop("time").to_zarr("weather.zarr", region={"space": region_update})

# produces
xr.open_zarr('weather.zarr/')

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (space: 3, time: 4)
Coordinates:
  * space         (space) <U2 'IA' 'IL' 'NY'
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-04
Data variables:
    measurements  (time, space) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(4, 2), meta=np.ndarray>
```